# Wird hier schwimmen gross-oder kleingeschrieben?

Tags: capitalization

Hallo bei folgendem Satz weiss ich nicht, ob es schwimmen oder Schwimmen geschrieben wird.

> "Im Sommer ist s/Schwimmen eine erholsame Freizeitbeschäftigung."

Da man die Artikelprobe anwenden kann —> "Im Sommer ist das Schwimmen..." dachte ich wird es großgeschrieben. Aber auf der anderen Seite wird in Verbindung mit "sein" immer kleingeschrieben oder liege ich falsch?

Danke schon mal im Voraus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Schwimmen* ist hier Subjekt des Satzes. Damit ist es ein Nomen und wird folglich groß geschrieben.

Dass ein Verb in Verbindung mit *sein* immer klein geschrieben wird, ist so nicht richtig, jedenfalls dann nicht, wenn *sein* Vollverb ist. Ein Verb wird aber klein geschrieben, wenn es zusammen mit *sein* als Hilfsverb eine zusammengesetzte Verbform bildet, z.B. das Perfekt: *Ich bin geschwommen*.

Comment: Die Anwort ist ja (in meinen trüben Augen) richtig. Ich verstehe nur den zweiten Absatz mit der Erklärung überhaupt nicht. Was hat das denn mit *sein* und *Vollverb* zu tun?

Comment: Ob ein Verb zusammen mit einer Form von *sein* groß oder klein geschrieben wird, kann davon abhängen, ob *sein* Vollverb oder Hilfsverb ist.

Comment: @Olafant: Wenn dir das mit den Voll- und Hilfsverben weiterhin unklar ist, kannst du ja eine Frage dazu stellen: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask Die Kommentare hier sind der falsche Ort um das abzuhandeln.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Ich verstehe Olafants Beitrag als Kommentar zur Antwort, nicht als Frage.Im Satz "Schwimmen ist in den letzten Jahren populärer geworden" ist "Sein" auch kein Vollverb, und trotzdem wird "Schwimmen" großgeschrieben. Es kommt einfach auf die genaue Verbindung mit "sein" an; ob Vollverb oder nicht, spielt dafür eigentlich keine Rolle.